# Simple vectorization of taking the product and then sum of a list-like object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a seemingly simple operation I want to do, and maybe I'm just blocked, but what's the quickest way of performing this calculation?

```
mret = 0
for i in range(1, len(monthly_rets)):
    mret += monthly_rets[i:].prod()
```

monthly_rets is an np.array of length 2-540 (ie. its length can vary from 2 to 540, it doesn't have to be an np.array) of monthly factor returns (shouldn't really matter for the question). There must be some clever trick out there I can use to avoid using that for-loop and speed things up a little?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`np.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) and [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). Something like this should work (at least for numpy arrays):

```
mret = monthly_rets[:0:-1].cumprod().sum()
```

`np.cumprod` computes the cumulative product of an array, meaning if you have an array `a` with three elements `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]` `a.cumprod()` will give you the array `[a[0], a[0]*a[1], a[0]*a[1]*a[2]]`. Now you want to have something like. This is done by using the slice `[:0:-1]`, which will traverse the array backwards ending with the second to last element such that `a[:0:-1].cumprod()` will give you `[a[2], a[1]*a[2]]`. `sum()` will then sum up all the elements to give you your result. (Thanks @B.M. for pointing out the correct slicing.)

Btw, I checked the performance benefit for an array of 540 random numbers (corresponding to your largest array), using `ipython`'s `%timeit`. I got a speed-up of 2.3ms/10µs=230. Even counting the caching effects that `%timeit` is warning about (probably incorrectly) you definitively have a speedup of at least 40.

Comment: monthly_rets[:0:-1] to have the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations, I made a slight modification to your formula which gives me the answer I'm after (the extra [:-1]):
    mret2 = monthly_rets[::-1][:-1].cumprod().sum()

Comment: Yes I just saw, that you wanted to exclude the `[0]` element. I updated my solution.